# Limit containing an unknown inverse function

Tags: calculus, limits, inverse-function

If$$
f(x) = x + \sin(x),\ g(y) =f^{-1}(y),$$
find$$
\lim_{y\to 0} \frac{2g(y)-y}{y^2}.
$$
Can you help me with this please? Thank you.

Comment: Why not get back to original $f$ by putting $g(y) =x, y=f(x) $ to get $(x-\sin x) /(x+\sin x) ^2$ and as $y\to 0,x\to 0$. The answer is not difficult to obtain if you divide the numerator / denominator by $x^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that $f$ and its inverse $g$ are a strictly increasing differentiable  function such that $g'(y)=1/f'(x)$ with $y=f(x)$ (take a look at [inverse functions and differentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_functions_and_differentiation)).

Now $g(0)=f(0)=0$ and by using L'Hopital we have that
$$\lim_{y\to 0} \frac{2g(y)-y}{y^2}=\lim_{y\to 0} \frac{2g'(y)-1}{2y}
=\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{2/f'(x)-1}{2f(x)}.$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: I'm blocked right there $\frac{1- \cos(x)}{2y(1+\cos(x))}$

Comment: Note that $y=f(x)$.